# How to get a value from url and auto populate the data based on the value using angularJS

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

my project works on Django and AngularJS. One of the functionality of the system is there will be a email send to the users if there is any settings has been created. The user can click on the link and he will redirected to the page with the value has been append it to the end of the url and the results auto-populate based on the value. I already have angularJS functions for that. But how to auto-populate based on the value from url? Can help me on it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we have url like `www.domain.com/yourapp?data=value`. Now we can get the value of data by using: `$scope.data = $routeParams.data` then you can use `$scope.data` as a variable.
You can refer [routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) and [here is an example](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/angularjs-novice-to-ninja/preview/using-routeparams-in-the-controller-6e0d5e2)

Comment: Thien, my url is not contains any query string. Looks like this `http://10.85.87.116:2133/xxx/aaaa/8BTEA`

Comment: It's same with my way. You can follow examples on the links above.